# make column headers unique sed or awk

Tags: sed, awk

I have a large space separated text file with non-unique column headers. I would like to make column headers unique by doing something like this using sed or awk. A new set of names begins with the column names

```
input    
index type colx...names paul peter sarah... names paul peter sarah.... names paul peter sarah

output
index type colx...0names 0paul 0peter 0sarah... 1names 1paul 1peter 1sarah.... 2names 2paul 2peter 2sarah
```

can you please help me with this?

Comment: My apologies, forgot to say that the file already has some other unique columns before the non-unique ones start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your actual files looks something more like this:

```
names paul peter sarah names paul peter sarah names paul peter sarah
data1 ...
data2 ...
data3 ...
```

If that is the case this will do the trick:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)$i=a[$i]++ $i}1' file
0names 0paul 0peter 0sarah 1names 1paul 1peter 1sarah 2names 2paul 2peter 2sarah
data1 ...
data2 ...
data3 ...
```

**EDIT:**

To skip the first 3 columns just start at column 4:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{for(i=4;i<=NF;i++)$i=a[$i]++ $i}1' file
index type colx 0names 0paul 0peter 0sarah 1names 1paul 1peter 1sarah 2names ...
data1 ...
data2 ...
data3 ...
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify stop at column?

Comment: Of course, you could have easily figured that out yourself however... just change `i<=NF` with `i<=10` or what ever value you need.

Answer (score 2):

this awk one-liner may help:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf "%s"(i==NF?"\n":" "),a[$i]++$i}'
```

test:

```
kent$  awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf "%s"(i==NF?"\n":" "),a[$i]++$i}'<<<"names paul peter sarah names paul peter sarah names paul peter sarah"
0names 0paul 0peter 0sarah 1names 1paul 1peter 1sarah 2names 2paul 2peter 2sarah
```

**EDIT** for the new requirement:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[$i]++; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)$i=(a[$i]>1)?a[$i]++-2$i:$i}7'
```

test: ( I shortened your example, but it should be the same problem)

```
kent$  awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[$i]++; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)$i=(a[$i]>1)?a[$i]++-2$i:$i}7'<<<"a b c x y z x y z"
a b c 0x 0y 0z 1x 1y 1z
```

Comment: The solution seems to modify the data as well. I was looking only to modify the first line